# Where are Chrome OS release notes published?

Tags: google-chrome-os

Where can I read Chrome OS official release notes? I searched but I could only find https://www.google.com/chromebook/whatsnew/ which is updated less regularly than once per release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since 2019, Chrome OS release notes are regularly published on the Chromebook community at https://support.google.com/chromebook/threads?hl=en&thread_filter=(pinned:true)

Enterprise-specific release notes are published at https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7679408